# Is there a way to check availability of a port number?

Tags: c++, networking, ip

Is there a way to check availability of a port number, without connecting, listening or binding?

Is there any function like `bool CheckPort(UINT port_num)?`

Comment: The result of such a hypothetical operation would be meaningless, since you could not possibly act on it. By the time you would actually try to bind to a port, someone else may already have taken it.

Comment: well this function is connect or bind

Comment: The thing is I need a way of automatic finding a good port number, other than binding to zero? For some reason when I try binding to 0, I got error code 10049

Comment: So make a candidate list of ports and try to bind to them, if one fail try next one. If all of them failed, let the OS find a port or you should show a warning or error message. It's the way many programs will do.

Comment: @Samer Did you consider looking up Winsock error 10049? It means you did something else wrong, specifically that the *address* you were binding to was wrong. You were on the right track then; you're on the wrong track with this question.

Comment: @MM. 'Many programs' such as what? I've never seen one. It's an extremely inefficient technique, and utterly pointless when the OS can do it for you in one system call.

Comment: @EJP: Read the question and comments again, OP wants to bind to specific ports not a random port. Everyone knows how to bind to a port by only one line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any connect/listen/bind, you need some OS magic to do it. For example in Windows you can try functions like [`GetExtendedTcpTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928.aspx) or [`GetExtendedUdpTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365930.aspx).

> The GetExtendedUdpTable/GetExtendedTcpTable function retrieves a table that contains a
>   list of UDP/TCP endpoints available to the application.

These retrieve lists so that you can iterate over it and get useful information. Check if any executing program is listening to that specific port or not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this: If you bind to port 0, a random port will be allocated. Then the `getsockname()` function can be used to find out the actual port used.

Comment: This is exactly the correct answer. He wants a random port: this gives him one. The technique the OP wants to use is irredeemably flawed. It amounts to asking the computer to predict the future. +1

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is *no*, because not connecting to a socket while still trying to check for availability doesn't really make much sense. How are you guaranteed that nobody else used that port while you're checking? You must `connect` to the port first.